# Two presentations of the Klein bottle

Tags: algebraic-topology, klein-bottle

In Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology*, Chapter 1, page 51, he describes two presentations of the Klein bottle:

[image]

The first one is the usual one, a square with opposite sides identified via the word $aba^{−1}b$, then Hatcher says that if one cuts the square along a diagonal and reassembles the resulting two triangles as shown in the figure, one obtains the other representation as a square with sides identified via the word $a^2c^2$.

**Question**: Does this process, which involves cutting and gluing, automatically imply the two presentations are equivalent?

Comment: Can you convince yourself that they must give the same surface? (Hint, ish: what if you do the gluing before the cutting rather than after?)

Comment: I am not sure whether you are asking a more general question - but what does cutting the surface (the Klein bottle) along the lines $a, b, c$ do?

Comment: Think of the cutting of the square giving you a space, $X$ say, comprising two triangles. The two pictures are then just two different ways of visualising how you can identify pairs of edges of the two triangles to get a Klein bottle.

Comment: @RobArthan But how do you know two ways are equivalent?

Comment: @MarkBennet Yes, I do want to ask the question more generally: suppose we cut and glue the square, and still get a topological square, then we identify the boundaries in a different way, does this process change the surface which it represents?

Comment: You know the two ways are equivalent because the Klein bottle is obtained by identifying the edges of a pair of triangles - which can be done all at once. The two options you have here are the result of choosing a different edge to identify first. In the end the pairs of edges end up identified in the same way. You can cut other surfaces into finite numbers of pieces. Beginning with the surface and cutting it into pieces guarantees that when you put the pieces back together you get the surface you started with,.

Comment: Could you straighten me out?  The Klein bottle isn't a group,  right?   Do you mean its fundamental group?   And out of curiosity,  what is that?

Comment: @pipe What do you mean? I didn't say anything about groups. The presentations are presentations of the Klein bottle.

Comment: Oh, I thought presentations were usually groups.   Plus you have the fundamental group tag.  Sorry.

Comment: @pipe No problem, I shouldn't have added the fundamental group tag. I just removed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just to summarize the comments:

The Klein bottle are two triangles with edges identified as follows:

[image]

We recognize the Klein bottle solely by the cycles on the boundaries of the two triangles,  which are $cab$ and $cb^{-1}a$. It doesn't matter how we arrange the two triangles, they can be put separately as above, or two $a$'s putting together, or two $b$'s putting together, or two $c$'s putting together.